# How to test hoverover text in Cucumber

Tags: testing, selenium, cucumber

I am using cucumber for testing the hover over text for the table Header text. since I am using a template I dont have identifiers for the table header so I am not sure how to target all the headers and compare it against the required value.

```
<th>
<a class="className" title="Title for Header1">header1</a>
</th>
<th>
<a class="className" title="Title for Header2">header2</a>
</th>
<th>
<a class="className" title="Title for Header3">header3</a>
</th>
```

Comment: could you show us what you have now?

Comment: I just added the sample code for Header

Comment: I am not sure how I can target each header and compare the title with the one I provide in Cucumber.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem identified is: You need to validate your `title` attribute for each `<th><a>`

Here is some pseudo-code on how to accomplish your task.  (in java)

```
WebElement elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("th > a"));

for (WebElement element : elements)
  assertTrue(element.getAttribute("title").equals("Some title"));
```